# Get Android xml preference files dynamically

Tags: android, android-preferences

Is there a way to get a list of only the xml preference files?  I would like to dynamically set sharedpreferences default values like so:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.somepreferencefile, true);
```

However I currently have 4 or 5 preference files that I am doing this for and I would like to not have to mod the code every time a new preference file is added.

I have stumbled across this:

```
final Field[] fields = R.xml.class.getDeclaredFields();
// add any other files you might have added
for (int i = 0, max = fields.length; i < max; i++) {
    try {
        final int resourceId = fields[i].getInt(new R.xml());
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, resourceId, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

However that will pull all xml files in the xml folder, which I don't want as every file might not be a preference file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a prefix in the preferences XML files you will be using (something like "pref_"). Then in your code, only get the XML files that start with the prefix you used. For example:

```
....
if (fields[i].getName().startsWith("pref")) {
    final int resourceId = fields[i].getInt(new R.xml());
    ...
}
....
```